# Permission Error | Apach Drill Query | HDFS

Tags: hadoop, ambari, apache-drill

I am trying to query parquet files present on a hdfs cluster via Apache Drill(distributed mode).
I have created a new storage plugin named 'hdfs' which contains the following **configuration**:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "hdfs://<my-name-node-host>:8020",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    }
  }
}
```

In the hadoop fs I have the sample file region.parquet in `/user/tj/` folder. It has the owner and group as `hdfs:hdfs` by default and i would like to keep it so.

But when i try to query it from Apache drill UI via following sql query :
`SELECT * FROM hdfs`.`/user/tj/region.parquet`
It throws the exception  as below :

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR:
>   RemoteException: Permission denied:
>   user=,
>   access=EXECUTE,
>   inode="/user/tj/region.parquet/.drill.parquet_metadata":hdfs:hdfs:-rw-r--r--
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:205)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1827)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getFileInfo(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:3972)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:851)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2313) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2309) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2307) [Error
>   Id: 24bf0cf0-0181-4c72-97ee-4b4eb98771bf on
>   :31010]

How do I fix this permission issue to query the hadoop cluster files using apache drill ?

How to execute the query as a hdfs user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have configure the user impersonation.You can follow the below link to give the view permission for the apache drill. I actually didn't use the apache drill so please update in comment if it works fine.

[Configure user impersonation link](http://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-user-impersonation/)

Comment: As per the docsm the clients for which user impersontation is not supported : Drill Web Console, REST API.
I am using drill web console so how to achieve the same.

Comment: Anyways, I started the drillbit service on all hosts as hdfs user as a quick fix - working now. Thank you for your help.